# Java Data Hierarchy and Row Mapping

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, jdbc

I have an application that needs to model some existing DB tables (I cannot change them) with a number of duplicated rows.  I'm trying to figure out a good design to reuse as much of the mapping code as possible so I don't have to duplicate a bunch of set calls.

Here is an example of two of the tables.

```
TIME_AND_EXPENSE_STAGING

Name               Null     Type           
------------------ -------- -------------- 
SEQ_NUM            NOT NULL NUMBER(31)     
DATETIME_STAMP              TIMESTAMP(6)   
DEPT_ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)   
EMPL_ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11)   
JOB_CODE           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)    
REGULAR_HRS        NOT NULL NUMBER(4,2)    
OVERTIME_HRS       NOT NULL NUMBER(4,2)    
MILES              NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)    
COMMENTS           VARCHAR2(4000) 

TIME_AND_EXPENSE_APPROVED

Name               Null     Type           
------------------ -------- -------------- 
SEQ_NUM            NOT NULL NUMBER(31)     
DATETIME_STAMP              TIMESTAMP(6)   
DEPT_ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)   
EMPL_ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11)   
JOB_CODE           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)    
REGULAR_HRS        NOT NULL NUMBER(4,2)    
OVERTIME_HRS       NOT NULL NUMBER(4,2)    
MILES              NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)    
COMMENTS           VARCHAR2(4000)     
APPROVE_TIME       NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
APPROVER_ID        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11)
```

I am using the Spring framework and the Spring RowMapper to populate the data objects.  I feel like there should be some graceful way to use inheritance or polymorphism or some design pattern that will prevent me from having to copy and paste a bunch of set statements.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally tend to like to use immutable objects when dealing with this sort of data. Imagine the following class:

```
public class TimeAndExpense {
    private final String jobCode;
    // and a bunch of other attributes such as department...

    // Then the additional data (approval data)
    private final Optional<String> approverId;
    private final Optional<Timestamp> approveTime;

    public TimeAndExpense(final String jobCode) {
        this(jobCode, null, null);
    }

    public TimeAndExpense(
                final String jobCode, 
                final Timestamp approveTime, 
                final String approverId) {

        this.jobCode = jobCode;
        // And the rest of the attributes...

        this.approveTime = Optional.ofNullable(approveTime);
        this.approverId = Optional.ofNullable(approverId);
    }

    public Optional<Timestamp> getApproveTime() {
        return approveTime;
    }

    public Optional<String> getApproverId() {
        return approverId;
    }

    public String getJobCode() {
        return jobCode;
    }

    public boolean isApproved() {
        return approverId.isPresent();
    }

    // Creates a new object with the approval data (immutable)
    public TimeAndExpense withApprovalData(final Timestamp approveTime, final String approverId) {
        return new TimeAndExpense(this.getJobCode(), approveTime, approverId);
    }
}
```

The method `withApprovalData` can be used to create a `TimeAndExpense`-object with the additional approval data. When used this way you can setup your `RowMapper`s like this:

```
// The RowMapper for the table TIME_AND_EXPENSE_STAGING
// More columns than JOB_CODE exists but are not part of the example
private final RowMapper<TimeAndExpense> timeAndExpenseRowMapper = 
        (rs, rowNum) -> new TimeAndExpense(rs.getString("JOB_CODE"));

// The RowMapper for the table TIME_AND_EXPENSE_APPROVED
// Reuse the timeAndExpenseRowMapper's mapping, then add additional approval data
private final RowMapper<TimeAndExpense> timeAndExpenseApprovedRowMapper =
        (rs, rowNum) -> timeAndExpenseRowMapper
                .mapRow(rs, rowNum) // use the timeAndExpenseRowMapper
                .withApprovalData(  // and add the additional approval data
                        rs.getTimestamp("APPROVE_TIME"),
                        rs.getString("APPROVER_ID"));
```

This delegation (one `RowMapper` uses another `RowMapper`) works well when the tables are very similar and enables a great deal of code reuse.

Inheritance is something that I personally try to use as little as possible [in favour of composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). But, for the domain model it might make sense to have some kind of base object (e.g. `Identifiable`) that contains e.g. an id (since e.g. the `Department`, `Employee` and `TimeAndExpense` objects all seem to contain an id an possibly even a timestamp).

Comment: Interesting approach.  Optional seems to be a new feature of 1.8.  We're not quiet there yet.  :D

Comment: @siliconsmiley - `Optional` and the lambdas are Java 8. For a Java 7 approach you can use `Optional` from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).